# Saber último index de um .each

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou a percorrer um `.each` e gostaria que na última posição apresentasse um `alert`. Para tal estou a tentar ir buscar a última posição do `index`:

```
if (index == len - 1) {
    alert("Última posição");
}
```

Código completo:

```
$.getJSON("/Contrato/CriarCopiarContrato", { agrupamento: $("#listaAgrupamentos").val() },
   function (result) {
      $.each(result, function (index, itemData) {
          if (index == len - 1) {
              alert("ultima");
          }
      });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basta você recuperar o tamanho - length do seu result. O código é mostrado a seguir:

```
$.getJSON("/Contrato/CriarCopiarContrato", { agrupamento: $("#listaAgrupamentos").val() },
   function (result) {
      var len = result.length;
      $.each(result, function (index, itemData) {
          if (index == len - 1) {
              alert("ultima");
          }
      });
});
```

Comment: Tinha essa linha comentada... Obrigado pelo reparo :)

Answer (score 0):

Além das formas citadas, já que está usando JQuery, pode usar o método [.last()](http://api.jquery.com/last/)

Exemplo:

```
var a = [1,2,3,4];
var lastEl = $(a).last()[0];
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3307002/1685571